# Access variable value where the name of variable is stored in a string java

Tags: java, swing

I am using JFrame and have a string containing the variable name. I want to get the value of that variable.

```
 String temp = "dim";
 double temp_value = Double.parseDouble(temp.getText());
```

where `dim` is name of variable in JFrame using swing library. 
Generally we use 2nd line of the code to get the value of the variable. How can we do in this case??

Comment: Is there any reason why you can provide a accessor method to get the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reflection API.

```
JFrame frame; // Instance of your JFrame ...
...
String temp = "dim";
Object value = frame.getClass().getField(temp).get(frame);
```

Comment: Generally the right answer. Anyway it depends on where vishnu has defined the variable (if he has defined it as a local variable there is nothing to do, but you should have pointed that in your answer) +1 anyway.

Comment: I understand this question as "i have a variable dim in a JFrame class and i whant to access value of this variable from a String variable containing "dim".